# Mobile ad support for java applications

Tags: java-me

Anyone know which ad-networks offer support for java applications? Most seem to only have iphone, android and mobile web support

Answer (score 1):

For JavaME there aren't many options these days.

Greystripe stopped support for JavaME in favor of iPhone and Android apps, which I thought was rather sad, because I had really great experience with Greystripe for 2 of our JavaME games back in the day.

For JavaME nowadays I can think of 3 options:

Nokia Ad Exchange (NAX)
http://developer.nokia.com/Distribute/NAX/

VServ
http://www.vserv.mobi/

And I believe Mobile Rated also still offers their own ad-system
http://www.mobilerated.com/

I have recently tried Nokia Ad Exchange, which is run by InnerActive, trying to serve a fullscreen ad (just like we did with Greystripe back in the day). But over 3500 requests by our users hasn't given a single ad, which means that we might as well just have given away our hard work for free.
This is very disappointing, and I have complained to them that they should stop offering a service they don't really offer anyway. They don't even deny it. Infact they reply that I should use banner ads instead, because there aren't many fullscreen ads. Such info would have been nice to have before we published.

In an older game we're using the ad-system from Mobile Rated. This at least is working, but not paying very much. It's taken years just to reach about $200. (With Greystripe we could make $900 in 3 months).

So last one to try out is Vserv, but I probably won't check 'em out anytime soon, since I don't have any apps in development at the moment.

Comment: Adfonic.com also seem to support J2ME.